# Pipe a command and redirect the output with command

Tags: shell, go

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    year, month, day := time.Now().Date()
    monthI := int(month)
    fmt.Println("toto")
    date := strconv.Itoa(year)+"_"+strconv.Itoa(monthI)+"_"+strconv.Itoa(day)
    nameSnapshot := "storedb@backup_"+date
    args := []string{"snapshot",nameSnapshot}
    cmd := exec.Command("zfs", args...)
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        os.Stderr.WriteString(err.Error())
    }
    args = []string{"send",nameSnapshot,"|","gzip",">","backup_"+date+".gz"}
    cmd = exec.Command("zfs", args...)
    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        os.Stderr.WriteString(err.Error())
    }


}
```

I would like to do it in one command.

My second line the zfs send command seems not working.

How to pipe and redirect the ouput in golang with cmd.exec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simplified version of how you would achieve this:

```
outfile, _ := os.OpenFile("backup.gz", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0755)

// your zfs command
zfs := exec.Command("zfs", "send", "storedb@backup")
gzip := exec.Command("gzip", "-cf") // gzip to stdout (-cf)
gzip.Stdin, _ = zfs.StdoutPipe()    // zfs stdout to gzip stdin
gzip.Stdout = outfile               // write output of gzip to outfile
gzip.Start()                        // gzip start waiting for input
zfs.Run()                           // zfs start command
gzip.Wait()                         // gzip wait for pipe to close
outfile.Close()
```

It is equivalent to this command in the shell:

```
zfs send stored@backup | gzip -cf > backup.gz
```

Comment: I believe your question only pertains to piping commands. The size of the output is totally another story and requires another question.

Comment: precise , simple and elegant